# Spoofing MAC Address on Micromax Juice 3

Tags: mac-address, micromax

I am a Micromax Juice 3 user, I have rooted my phone using the KingoRoot App. Then I have installed the xposed installer to use various modules for android. Now I want the ability to spoof my mac address, I have tried multiple ways as suggested in some previous questions like installing terminal emulator and using commands like

busybox ifconfig eth0/wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

or

iplink set eth0/wlan0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

But it gives me an error : "operation not supported"

I have tried using apps to do it, like Pry-fi or Mac Changer but they also do not seem to work. For eg. in Pry-fi I always see my current and original address as the same. I have unlocked my bootloader (if that's a pre-requisite -I am not sure) using fastboot oem unlock command which wiped my device which makes me believe that unlocking was successful.

Anybody has any ideas how can I successfully make it work?

Comment: Try this app: **[Chamele MAC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryptotel.chamelemac&hl=en)**. Also try this Xposed module: **[Phone ID Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoneinfo.changer)**. If neither works, disable SE Linux by `setenforce 0` and try again..

Comment: And for additional candidates, see my app list on [Network Spoofer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sniffspoof#group_390)s :)

Comment: @GokulNC The Chamele Mac app works for me, I can see the new MAC Address when I go to Status under Settings but now weirdly enough I can access internet using my mobile browser but none of my apps seem to be  able to access internet or connect to the network. Would you know why this is happening?